# Wired USB headset with Virtual Surround only recognized as stereo

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, alsa, headset

I recently bought a wired USB headset with 7.1 virtual surround, which, according to the manufacturer, supports GNU/Linux and Chrome OS too. According to what I read on the comments, Windows users seem to be happy with the virtual surround feature, and I'd like to have the same on Ubuntu MATE 22.04.1. The problem is that it is only recognized as stereo (Pavucontrol shows only front left and front right channels for "USB PnP Audio Device Digital Stereo (IEC958)" and the port is listed as "Digital Output (S/PDIF)") and I couldn't find a way to play my files with AC-3 sound in 5.1, they're all downmixed to stereo. In the Output Devices tab of Pulse Audio Volume Control, I ticked the AC-3 checkbox in the Advanced settings for this device, but that didn't help.

In lsusb it the headset appears as

`Bus 003 Device 015: ID 0c76:161f JMTek, LLC. USB PnP Audio Device`

On [Linux Hardware][1] database, it appears this is a rather common headset.

The alsamixer command, after choosing the appropriate sound card, shows the following:
[alsamixer screenshot][2]

Any help would be really appreciated, please give me my 5.1 virtual surround. Below you can find some command outputs in order to provide more information.

```
Here's the output of aplay -l

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC3227 Analog [ALC3227 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Device [USB PnP Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Here's the output of aplay -L

````
$ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=0
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=HDMI
    HDA ATI HDMI
    USB Stream Output
hw:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC3227 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC3227 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=Generic
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC3227 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC3227 Analog
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC3227 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround41:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC3227 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC3227 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround71:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC3227 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC3227 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=Generic
    HD-Audio Generic
    USB Stream Output
surround51:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC3227 Analog
    Downmix to stereo 5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC3227 Analog
    Downmix to stereo 4.0 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
hw:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=Device
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround41:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround71:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=Device
    USB PnP Audio Device
    USB Stream Output
surround51:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    Downmix to stereo 5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB PnP Audio Device, USB Audio
    Downmix to stereo 4.0 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers```



  [1]: http://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0c76-161f
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lAwM.gif
````